# Why can't I see previous and next arror in my carousel component in bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Everything is going great, but I don't see this right and left arrors in my slide show. What should I do to fix it? I did the exactly what is in bootstrap documentation. I tried to look at on google, but couldn't find anything related to this issue. I need your help with this issue, please.
(it still doesnt upload my post, so filling the blanks)

```css
body .container-fluid {
    padding: 0; /* the left and right side of body was a bit empty. When i did margin:0 padding:0 for the body it didn't work, but on google developer tools I saw that container-fluid had padding right, and left. So making them 0.*/
}
body {
    text-align: center;
}
.title-image {
    width:100%;
}

.download-button {
    margin: 15px 13px;
}

.big-heading {
    font-family:  "Montserrat", "sans-serif";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    line-height:1.5;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.first_part {
    color: white;
    background-color: #F27E48;
    text-align: left;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 3% 3% 6% 5% !important;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    
}

#courses {
    padding:50px 100px 50px;
    background-color: azure;
}
#courses>p{ /*only for child p of courses id, not grandchild etc */
    width:60%;
    margin: 18px auto 24px;
}
.card-body p{
    text-align: left;
}

#how {
    padding:50px 70px 50px;
    background-color: rgb(243, 243, 178);
}
#how img {
    height:280px;
    width:330px;
}
.row div {
    margin-top:10px;
}

.outcome {
    width:70%;
    margin:20px auto;
    background-color: rgb(236, 223, 223) ;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.big {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;

}
#outcomes {
    padding:50px 70px 50px;
}
#outcomes a{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#outcomes a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}
.student-image {
    height: 350px;
    width: 450px;
}
#comments {
    padding: 50px 70px 50px;
    background-color: azure;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data Science Course Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Noto+Serif&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <section class="first_part" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
<!--all of element appeared when i wrote navbar-expand-lg-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">        
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-python"> Python Bootcamp</i>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#courses">Courses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#how">How We Work</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#outcomes">Outcomes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#comments">Contact</a>
                        </li> 
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>                 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Title -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6"> <!-- so it will fill 50% of width on screen of laptops, and bigger screens-->
                    <h1 class="big-heading">Download the best Python bootcamp on your device, and start to study now.</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-danger download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-light btn-outline-primary download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>                    

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img class="title-image" src="image.jpg" alt="classroom-image">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>            
    </section>

    <!-- Courses -->
    <section id="courses">
        <h2>Our Course Options</h2>
        <p>All of our programs provide job guarantee. No matter where you live, and what nationality you are. Our proven system works all around the world.</p>

        <div class="row">
<!-- for laptops and bigger screens one row takes 33.3% of total width, for small screens it takes 50% -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Online Program</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>400$ / mo</h4>
                        <p>Unlimited watch time for the saved videos</p>
                        <p>5 mins talking to the instructor per day on skype</p>
                        <p>Unlimited limit of asking questions on the app</p>
                        <p>6 months</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark col-12">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Full Time Program</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>1300$ / mo</h4>
                        <p>Unlimited watch time for the saved videos</p>
                        <p>20 mins talking to the instructor per day on skype</p>
                        <p>Unlimited limit of asking questions on the app</p>
                        <p>2 months</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col-12">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>Part Time Program</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>700$ / mo</h4>
                        <p>Unlimited watch time for the saved videos</p>
                        <p>10 mins talking to the instructor per day on skype</p>
                        <p>Unlimited limit of asking questions on the app</p>
                        <p>4 months</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark col-12">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- How we work -->
    <section id="how">
        <h2>How We Work</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <p>One-on-one mentorship and guidance.</p>
                <img src="coding.jpg" alt="coding-image">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <p>Study schedules that fit with your life.</p>
                <img src="clock.jpg" alt="coding-image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>In-person meetups, workshops.</p>
                <img src="meetup.jpg" alt="meetup-image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Outcomes -->
    <section id="outcomes">
        <div class="outcome">

            <!-- Tabs navs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="fulltime-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#fulltime" role="tab" aria-controls="fulltime" aria-selected="true">Full Time Program</a>
                
                </li>
    
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="parttime-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#parttime" role="tab" aria-controls="parttime" aria-selected="false">Part Time Program</a>
                   
                </li>
    
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="online-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#online" role="tab" aria-controls="online" aria-selected="false">Online Program</a>
                     
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tabs Content-->
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTab-content">
                <div
                  class="tab-pane fade show active"
                  id="fulltime"
                  role="tabpanel"
                  aria-labelledby="fulltime-tab"
                >
                    <p class="big">$70,000</p>
                    <p class="small">Median pay rate graduates reported earning.</p>
                    <p class="big">80%</p>
                    <p class="small">Employed in-field within 90 days of graduation.</p>
                </div>

                <div
                  class="tab-pane fade"
                  id="parttime"
                  role="tabpanel"
                  aria-labelledby="parttime-tab"
                >
                    <p class="big">$60,000</p>
                    <p class="small">Median pay rate graduates reported earning.</p>
                    <p class="big">75%</p>
                    <p class="small">Employed in-field within 110 days of graduation.</p>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="tab-pane fade"
                  id="online"
                  role="tabpanel"
                  aria-labelledby="online-tab"
                >
                    <p class="big">$40,000</p>
                    <p class="small">Median pay rate graduates reported earning.</p>
                    <p class="big">65%</p>
                    <p class="small">Employed in-field within 150 days of graduation.</p>  
                </div> 
            </div>   
        </div>     
    </section>

    <!-- Comments -->
    <section id="comments">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <p>I took the fulltime program course. It was amazing. Up to date curriculum, and the best instructors in their field</p>
                    <img src="student1.jpg" class="student-image" alt="student-photo">
                    <em>Selena, Miami</em>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <p>I took the part time program course, and I got full stack python developer job only in 20 days within graduation.</p>
                    <img src="student2.jpg" class="student-image" alt="student-photo">
                    <em>Anna, Moscow</em>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <p>This course made me job ready. Don't waste time with other time wasting courses. This is what you have been looking for!</p>
                    <img src="student3.jpg" class="student-image" alt="student-photo">
                    <em>Taylor, Paris</em>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>




    </section>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Background colour and button colour are white.

Either add a background color, like this:

```
#comments {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/yLaxyyV

or change the colour of the buttons, like this:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23ff0000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23ff0000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
```

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49017805/11171286

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/qBaMEdK

Comment: But the background color for comment section, I made azure before. Why didnt it show me the buttons, since i changed the background color? Oh I got my mistake. Azure is like white, whitish color, so button isnt seen. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Azure is a very light colour. For testing purposes always use red, blue, green.