# How to customize controls and indicators in BootstrapVue's Carousel component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

The code looks as following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-carousel
      id="carousel-upper"
      v-model="slide"
      :interval="3000"
      fade
      controls
      indicators
      @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
      @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
    >
      <b-carousel-slide
        img-src="https://licota.ru/system/sliders/attachments/55ba/10cf/7372/763c/8600/0002/full/banner-2.jpg?1438257358"
      ></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide
        img-src="https://licota.ru/system/sliders/attachments/55ba/10cf/7372/763c/8600/0003/full/banner-3.jpg?1438257359"
      ></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide
        img-src="https://licota.ru/system/sliders/attachments/55ba/10ce/7372/763c/8600/0001/full/banner-1.jpg?1438257358"
      ></b-carousel-slide>
      <b-carousel-slide
        img-src="https://licota.ru/system/sliders/attachments/55ba/10ce/7372/763c/8600/0000/full/banner-0.jpg?1438257357"
      ></b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { CarouselData } from '../types/carousel'
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  data: (): CarouselData => {
    return {
      slide: 0,
      sliding: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSlideStart(slide: number) : void {
      this.sliding = true
    },
    onSlideEnd(slide: number) : void {
      this.sliding = false
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style lang="sass" module>
  ?
</style>
```

The screenshot of component with HTML:

[image]

For example I would like to make arrow bigger and of different color and have circles instead of short lines.

I've tried a lot of things, but I don't understand how to find and change Bootstrap's classes through Vue.js' style mechanism.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249541/change-arrow-colors-in-bootstraps-carousel   Bootstrap Vue uses Bootstrap styles so these answers are what you want

Comment: I've looked at it, but how to write it? I've tried as they did, but it didn't work.

Comment: It could be the `<style>` tag's `module` attribute blocking it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<style>` tag has the `module` attribute for [CSS Modules](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage) but this is probably blocking whatever styles you are trying to apply to the carousel, so remove that first if it's not intentional.

To adjust the size of the chevron controls, use `height` and `width` on the icon classes:

```css
.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

Color is trickier because the chevron is actually a `background-image` SVG (which is why height/width are necessary rather than `font-size`, for example).  For those, do the following:

```css
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23ff0000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23ff0000' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
```

Change the `fill` attribute hex value as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Using the approach of Dan, I used this for styling the indicators:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
      border-color: #e100ff;
      border-width: 12px;
      border-style: none solid none solid;
      background-color: #e100ff;
      height: 2px;
      margin: 0 16px;
      opacity: 1;
      padding: 1px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .carousel-indicators li::after {
      bottom: -7px;
      content: none;
      left: -7px;
      padding: 1px;
      position: absolute;
      right: -7px;
      top: -7px;
    }
    .carousel-indicators li.active {
      background-color: #7f00ff;
      border-color: #7f00ff;
      border-width: 12px;
      border-style: none solid none solid;
    }
```

Saw in https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/discussions/6264